# no me anda la pag angular

Tags: angular

y todavia no puedo lanzar bien mmi pagina, la cosa es que estaba haciendo una tabla con angular material, teniendo mi modulo compartido, llamado "shared", y lo importo a mi dashboardRoutingModule, pero, el componente no me lo quiere reconocer, estoy trabajando desde codesandbox.la tabla se encuentra en el componente llamado "usuarios".

este es el dashboardModule.

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


 import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
 import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
declarations: [],
imports: [

BrowserModule,
RouterModule,
CommonModule,
DashboardRoutingModule,
],
 })
 export class DashoardModule {}
```

este es el dashboardRoutingModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

 import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { ReportesComponent } from './reportes/reportes.component';
import { UsuariosComponent } from './usuarios/usuarios.component';
 import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

const route: Routes = [
  {
   path: 'dashboard',
   component: DashboardComponent,
   children: [
  { path: 'reportes', component: ReportesComponent },
  { path: 'usuarios', component: UsuariosComponent },
   ],
 },
];

@NgModule({
 declarations: [DashboardComponent],
 imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(route),      SharedModule],
  exports: [RouterModule],
 })
  export class DashboardRoutingModule {}
```

este es el dashboard.html

```
  <mat-card class="card">
    <mat-card-content>
      <p>
       <mat-toolbar>
       <span>My Dashboard</span>
      
      <span class="example-spacer"></span>
        
        <a mat-stroked-button routerLink="/usuarios" >User</a>
        <a mat-stroked-button routerLink="/reportes" >Report</a>
        
        <span class="example-spacer"></span>
        
             <button mat-stroked-button routerLink="/login"     color="primary"><mat-icon  aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example    home icon" fontIcon="logout"></mat-icon></button>
           
         </mat-toolbar>
         </p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card >
    <router-outlet>
    </router-outlet>
```

y este es el componente que supuestamente es el problema.
usuario.html

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content >
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

          <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
                The actual rendered columns are set as a property   on the row definition" -->
        
          <!-- Position Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
          </ng-container>
        
          <!-- Name Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
          </ng-container>
        
          <!-- Weight Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
          </ng-container>
        
          <!-- Symbol Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
          </ng-container>
        
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
        
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

disculpen la desprolijidad, no tengo mucha idea de como usar esta plataforma, pero, realmente les agradesco su ayuda.

Comment: Agrega `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` en el HTML de DashboardComponent.

Comment: no, ya lo tenia colocado el router outlet, en el dashboard, pero, me sigue apareciendo que no tengo nada enrutado, es mas en la pagina me sale cannot get

Comment: Agrega el código del DashboardComponent (html y TS), pero todo el código como texto (no en imágenes)

Comment: Parece que tienes declarado el DashboardComponent en el Routing.

Comment: si, esta declarado ahi, para poder usar el routerLink y desde dicho modulo poder pasar las rutas, esta mal hecho??

Comment: Hm yo nunca lo he puesto así, solo quita la línea `declarations: [DashboardComponent]`

Comment: ahi lo solucione, colocando el modulo shared tambien en el dasboardModule, gracias igual